# Eloquent Query Timestamp difference

Tags: php, laravel-5

I'm trying to fetch 5 records from my Model where the last updated time and the current time have a difference of X minutes.

Here is my code

```
 $servers = BareMetal::where('updated_at', '>=', date('Y-m-d H:i:s',strtotime("+ 10 Minutes")) )->take(5)->get();
```

Basically i'm trying to get records which havn't been updated for X minutes.

Comment: ...and question is...? :-)

Comment: the above code doesn't seem to work :(

Comment: I just need something which will get 5-10 records which were last updated X minutes / hours ago

Comment: What is the error returned? In case you have no error but the query returns an empty result set, are you able to check directly the database to see if there actually are records that were updated in the last x minutes?